# ObservableCollection is not persisted in built-in dictionary

Tags: c#, xamarin

In my app I have some data that I need to persist. Until now I had no problems using the built-in dictionary and persisting the primitive types. The problems started when i wanted to save ObservableCollection. According to [this article](https://developer.telerik.com/products/ui-for-xamarin/5-helpful-xamarin-developer-tips/) it is possible (part 3. Data Persistence). In my app I used this code:

```
if (!App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("phist"))
{
     App.Current.Properties.Add("phist", DataBase.phist);
     App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
}
else
{
     App.Current.Properties["phist"] = DataBase.phist;
     App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
}
```

(DataBase is a static class that I'm using to send data between pages in the application)

Using the code above I'm saving the DataBase.phist ObservableCollection (with strings). But when I restart my app and try to get the data there is no such key like "phist"

```
        ObservableCollection<string> temp_coll = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(temp_coll.Count);
        if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("phist"))
        {
            temp_coll = App.Current.Properties["phist"] as ObservableCollection<string>;
            for (int i = 0; i < temp_coll.Count; i++)
            {
                DataBase.phist.Add(temp_coll[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("temp collection no " + i + ": " + temp_coll[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("phist collection no " + i + ": " + DataBase.phist[i]);
            }

        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No such key");
```

The output on console is "No such key".
When I try to read the saved data without closing the app there aren't any problems with finding or reading the key but in the output I have thousands of lines (with temp_coll.Count equals to 1 or 2).

To sum up my question: Is it possible to persist whole ObservableCollection in built-in dictionary? If yes how? And if it's not possible what are other solutions to saving it?

Thank you in advance.